# EF Case Sensitivity for Properties

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am currently running into this bug

**The entity type Person is not part of the model for the current context.**

I generated this bug by changing **line 284** in the model1.tt (if you do not give the edmx a name it will give you model1) to the below code. I did this because our convention is to have camalCase database column names and PascalCase object property names. The below code will turn a camalCase column name into a PascalCase object property name ,as described below.

```
string.Format("{0}{1}",_code.Escape(edmProperty).Substring(0,1).ToUpper(),_code.Escape(edmProperty).Substring(1)),
```

Entity Generated by T4 template

```
public partial class Person
{
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

Table Definition

```
CREATE TABLE Person ( personId int, age int))
```

The problem occurs when, I try to do an integration test

`_context.Person.toList();`

When any code is run that interacts with the Database the previously described error occurs. How can I fix my solution so I can have PascalCase properties names and camelCase database column names and work as expected?

** EDIT **

I am using EF 5 and have no access to EF 6

This is also using Database-First

** EDIT 2**

```
   public string Property(EdmProperty edmProperty)
    {
        return string.Format(
            CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
            "[Column(\"{5}\")]\n{0} {1} {2} {{ {3}get; {4}set; }}",
            Accessibility.ForProperty(edmProperty),
            _typeMapper.GetTypeName(edmProperty.TypeUsage),
            _code.Escape(edmProperty),
           //_code.Escape(string.Format("{0}{1}",_code.Escape(edmProperty).Substring(0,1).ToUpper(),_code.Escape(edmProperty).Substring(1))),
            _code.SpaceAfter(Accessibility.ForGetter(edmProperty)),
            _code.SpaceAfter(Accessibility.ForSetter(edmProperty)),
            _code.Escape(edmProperty));
    }
```

This is my modified t4 template. The commented out code doesnt work, The line above it does. (With My Integration Test)

Comment: This is not the way to do it. use [Code-first conventions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj819164.aspx).

Comment: @GertArnold  I do not have access to ef6

Comment: whats not working sounds like you sorted it. the tt files usually have built in options for this. but if you have alrdy got that working... then I would give us the error your getting as it sounds fine.

Comment: @Seabizkit. That is the error I am getting. The entity type Person is not part of the model for the current context.  When i turn the T4 template back to its default, my test works fine. When I insert that Line of coding forcing the T4 template to turn all properties into PascalCase, that is when the error comes.